# I want to format the list of figures in the same fashion as the toc.i-e chapter no, chapter bar and below the list of figures of that chapter

Tags: formatting

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% fancy heading  \section %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\titleformat{\section}[block]%              
    {\huge\bfseries%
     \tikz[overlay] \shade[left color=teal,right color=white,] (0,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth,1em);}%    
    {\thesection}%                   
    {1em}%
    {#1}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% fancy heading  \chapter %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\gdef\chapterlabel{}
  \normalfont\rmfamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
{\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
    {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=cyan] (0,0) rectangle
        (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[anchor=east,xshift=.9\paperwidth,rectangle,
        rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
        fill=teal]
        {\color{white}\chapterlabel#1};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{0pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{\hfill}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\newtcbox{\chapternumberbox}[1][]{%
  colback=blue!50!black,
  colupper={white},
  fontupper={\bfseries\large},
  valign=center,
  size=small,
  nobeforeafter,
  equal height group=chaptertoc,
  #1,
}




\newtcolorbox{chapternamebox}[1][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw,
  valign=center,
  interior style={left color={white!30!blue},right color={blue}},
  colframe={gray},
  boxrule={1pt},
  colupper={white},
  size=small,
  fontupper={\bfseries\large},
  nobeforeafter,
  equal height group=chaptertoc,
  #1,
}

% A wrapper command
\newcommand{\mychapternamebox}[3][]{%
  \begin{chapternamebox}[#1]
    #2\hfill#3%
  \end{chapternamebox}%
}


\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
  {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\chapternumberbox{\protect\chaptername{} \thechapter}\protect\mychapternamebox[width={12cm}]{#1}{\thepage}}%%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}%
}{}{}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{Introduction}

\section{hockey}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{a}
\caption{ZnO Particles}
\end{figure}

\section{football}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Research Statement}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{a}
\caption{Nano Particles}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution only adds the LOF titles to the chapters which need it.  First, it saves the chapter title and page number as global macros.  Then it patches the figure environment to add the LOF title if the figure counter is zero (first figure in chapter).

Note, this assumes that every figure has a `\caption`, but I wanted to stay away from patching `\caption` as this would conflict with certain document classes.

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% fancy heading  \section %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\titleformat{\section}[block]%              
    {\huge\bfseries%
     \tikz[overlay] \shade[left color=teal,right color=white,] (0,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth,1em);}%    
    {\thesection}%                   
    {1em}%
    {#1}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% fancy heading  \chapter %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\gdef\chapterlabel{}
  \normalfont\rmfamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
{\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
    {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=cyan] (0,0) rectangle
        (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[anchor=east,xshift=.9\paperwidth,rectangle,
        rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
        fill=teal]
        {\color{white}\chapterlabel#1};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{0pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{\hfill}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\newtcbox{\chapternumberbox}[1][]{%
  colback=blue!50!black,
  colupper={white},
  fontupper={\bfseries\large},
  valign=center,
  size=small,
  nobeforeafter,
  equal height group=chaptertoc,
  #1,
}




\newtcolorbox{chapternamebox}[1][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw,
  valign=center,
  interior style={left color={white!30!blue},right color={blue}},
  colframe={gray},
  boxrule={1pt},
  colupper={white},
  size=small,
  fontupper={\bfseries\large},
  nobeforeafter,
  equal height group=chaptertoc,
  #1,
}

% A wrapper command
\newcommand{\mychapternamebox}[3][]{%
  \begin{chapternamebox}[#1]
    #2\hfill#3%
  \end{chapternamebox}%
}


\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
  {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\chapternumberbox{\thechapter}\protect\mychapternamebox[width={12cm}]{#1}{\thepage}}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}%
  \xdef\chaptertitle{#1}% save chapter title
  \xdef\chapterpage{\thepage}% save current page number
}{}{}

\let\oldfigure=\figure
\def\figure{\ifnum\value{figure}=0\relax
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}%
  \addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{\protect\chapternumberbox{\thechapter}\protect\mychapternamebox[width={12cm}]{\chaptertitle}{\chapterpage}}%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}%
\fi\oldfigure}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{Introduction}

\section{hockey}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image-a}
\caption{ZnO Particles}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image-a}
\caption{Nano Particles}
\end{figure}

\section{football}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Research Statement}

\end{document}
```

---

This version uses `\label` and `\pageref` to produce the page number, which will delay expanding `\thepage` until the page is shipped.

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% fancy heading  \section %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\titleformat{\section}[block]%              
    {\huge\bfseries%
     \tikz[overlay] \shade[left color=teal,right color=white,] (0,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth,1em);}%    
    {\thesection}%                   
    {1em}%
    {#1}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% fancy heading  \chapter %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\gdef\chapterlabel{}
  \normalfont\rmfamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
{\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
    {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=cyan] (0,0) rectangle
        (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[anchor=east,xshift=.9\paperwidth,rectangle,
        rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
        fill=teal]
        {\color{white}\chapterlabel#1};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{0pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{\hfill}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\newtcbox{\chapternumberbox}[1][]{%
  colback=blue!50!black,
  colupper={white},
  fontupper={\bfseries\large},
  valign=center,
  size=small,
  nobeforeafter,
  equal height group=chaptertoc,
  #1,
}




\newtcolorbox{chapternamebox}[1][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw,
  valign=center,
  interior style={left color={white!30!blue},right color={blue}},
  colframe={gray},
  boxrule={1pt},
  colupper={white},
  size=small,
  fontupper={\bfseries\large},
  nobeforeafter,
  equal height group=chaptertoc,
  #1,
}

% A wrapper command
\newcommand{\mychapternamebox}[3][]{%
  \begin{chapternamebox}[#1]
    #2\hfill#3%
  \end{chapternamebox}%
}


\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
  {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\chapternumberbox{\thechapter}\protect\mychapternamebox[width={12cm}]{#1}{\thepage}}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}%
  \xdef\chaptertitle{#1}% save chapter title
  \label{chapter\thechapter}% set up \pageref
}{}{}

\let\oldfigure=\figure
\def\figure{\ifnum\value{figure}=0\relax
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}%
  \addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{\protect\chapternumberbox{\thechapter}\protect\mychapternamebox[width={12cm}]{\chaptertitle}%
    {\pageref{chapter\thechapter}}}%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}%
\fi\oldfigure}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{Introduction}

\section{hockey}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image-a}
\caption{ZnO Particles}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image-a}
\caption{Nano Particles}
\end{figure}

\section{football}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Research Statement}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Johan Kormylo Suprub ! Marvellous. You did that. Thank u very much for this cooperation. Keep it up.Best wishes

Comment: @ Johan Kormylo Sir there is minor issue. the list of figures and list of tables the first chapter page number show roman page numbering(incorrect page number iv whereas correct page number is 1 .). while other chapters show correct  page numbers.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out this code.  Personally, I avoid titlesec as unneeded and confusing.  It should be noted that \addcontentsline automatically adds \thepage as an argument to \contentsline.  Presumably it is being ignored, but I can't be sure.

Comment: @ John Kormylo. But it does ignore only  for 1 chapter. For other Chapters it works fine

Comment: @ John Kormylo.You have done that. Thank u very much

Answer (score 2):

In the second part of your

```
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  % stuff here
}{%
  % more stuff here about toc
}
```

add in

```
more stuff here about lof
```

That is, repeat the `toc` stuff but using `lof` as the file name.

Comment: Sir i m unable to do that.

Comment: Why can't you do this, when the reason is known maybe another solution is possible.

Comment: @ Sir albert i tried to apply the above solution. but i m not sure whether i applied correctly or not. i m a new user of latex. i need your expert solution

Comment: @ibrarhussain Why can't you change your own code? Please explain. Or is it that you do not understand what I said? If the latter then I am prepared to edit and display your own code but really why should I go to all the extra bother when I have other things to do (GOM)?

Comment: @Peter Wilson Sir honestly speaking i m not an expert in latex. So i could not understand your solution.

Comment: Look at your code.  After `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}%` add `\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}%` 
  `\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{\protect\chapternumberbox{\protect\chaptername{} \thechapter}\protect\mychapternamebox[width={12cm}]{#1}{\thepage}}%` `\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}%`

Comment: @Johan Kormylo. Thank u very much sir u have nailed it. Its awesome.So nice of u. Just one thing i want if u can help me out.I want to add only those chapters names which contain figures. The chapters without figures i dont want to add.